# Subsection of grid as input to cnn

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have two huge grids (input and output) representing some spatial data of the same area. I want to be able to generate the output pixel-by-pixel by feeding a neural network a small part of the input grid, around the pixel of interest.

The naive way of training and evaluating on the CNN would be to extract sections separately, and giving those to the fit() function. But if the sub-grid the CNN operates on is e.g. a 256×256 area of the input, then I would copy each data point 65536 (!!!) times per epoch.

So is there any way to have karas just use subsections of a bigger data structure as training?

To me, this sounds a bit like training RNN's on sequencial sections of a data series, instead of copying each section separately.

The performance consideration is mainly in the case of evaluating the model. I want to use this model to generate output grid of a huge geographical area (denmark) with a resolution of 12,5 cm

Comment: Can i ask why this question has been downvoted? I tried to put significant effort into researching beforehand, and explaining both the problem and motivation as easily as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are looking for a [fully convolutional network](https://www.quora.com/How-is-Fully-Convolutional-Network-FCN-different-from-the-original-Convolutional-Neural-Network-CNN) (FCN).

By using only layers that scale in size with their inputs (banishing the use of dense layers specifically), an FCN is able to produce an output with a spatial range that grows proportionally with that of the input — typically, the ouput has the same resolution as the input, as in your case.

If your inputs are very large, you can still train an FCN on subimages. Then for inference, you can

- run the network on your entire image: indeed, sometimes the inputs are too big to be batched together during training, but can be feed alone for inference.
- or split your input into subimages and tile the results back. In that case, I would probably use overlapping tiles to avoid potential border effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably go well with a `Sequence` generator.

You will still have to create slices for each batch, but taking slices isn't slow at all compared with the CNN operations.

And by using a `keras.utils.Sequence`, the generation of the batches is parallel with the model's execution, so no penalty:

```py
class GridGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, originalGrid_maybeFileName, outputGrid, subGridSize):
        self.originalGrid = originalGrid_maybeFileName 
        self.outputGrid = outputGrid

        self.subgridSize = subgridSize

    def __len__(self):

        #naive implementation, if grids are squares and the sizes are multiples of each other
        self.divs = self.originalGrid.shape[:,:,1] // self.subgridSize

        return self.divs * self.divs

    def __getitem__(self,i):

        row, column = divmod(i, self.divs)

        #using channels_last
        x= self.originalGrid[:,row:row+self.subgridSize, column:column+self.subgridSize]
        y= self.outputGrid[:,row:row+self.subgridSize, column:column+self.subgridSize]

        return x,y
```

If the full grid doesn't fit your PC's memory, then you should find ways of loading parts of the grid at a time. (Use the generator to load these parts)

Create the generator and train with `fit_generator`:

```py
generator = GridGenerator(xGrid, yGrid, subSize)

#you can create additional generators to take a part of that as training and another part as validation

model.fit_generator(generator, len(generator), ...., workers = 4)
```

The `workers` argument determines how many batches will be loaded in parallel before sent to the model.